# Group the values for a certain time interval and calculate the means

Tags: r

I am studying data of soil respiration (CO2 flux) over the time. The soil respiration is measured automatically every 10 minutes.

My dataset contains the following colums :

> - Year
> - Day
> - Hours
> - Minutes
> - Time in decimal units (Day + Hours/24 + Minutes/(24*60)
> - Soil respiration

The soil respiration is measured every 10 mins, so I have 144 values per day. 
For a specific analysis, I need to have the means of the values each 3 hours for each day.

> - 0h : 1 value at 00:00 the first day and then mean of the values between 21:10 and 00:00
> - 3h (mean of 0:10, 0:20, 0:30, 0:40, 0:50, 1:0, 1:10, 1:20, [...] 2:50; 3:00) mean of 18 values.
> - 6h (mean of the values between 3:10 and 6:00)
> - 12h (mean of the values between 6:10 and 12:00)
> - 15h (mean of the values between 12:10 and 15:00)
> - 18h (mean of the values between 15:10 and 18:00)
> - 21h (mean of the values between 18:10 and 21:00)
> - 00h (mean of the values between 21:10 and 00:00)

etc... 
So for each day I would like to obtain 8 values of soil respiration and each value is a mean value of 18 values.

How could I program this with R ? 
I have really big dataset, so I can't do it manually for each day.

Example of the dataset :

```
Year =c(2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014)
Day= c(274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274,274)
Hours= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
Minutes = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,0,10,20,30,40,50,0,10,20,30,40,50,0,10,20,30,40,50) 
Time_Dec=c(274.000,274.007,274.014,274.021,274.028,274.035,274.042,274.049,274.056,274.063,274.069,274.076,274.083,274.090,274.097,274.104,274.111,274.118,274.125,274.132,274.139,274.146,274.153,274.160)
Flux=c(0.84,0.88,0.91,0.95,0.98,1.02,0.84,0.87,0.91,0.94,0.98,1.01,0.83,0.87,0.90,0.94,0.97,1.01,0.83,0.87,0.90,0.94,0.97,1.00)
```

So, I would like to keep the first value and then have the mean for the 18th following values (until `Time_Dec= 274.125`)

Comment: You could use `cut` to group the values.  It might be better if you show a small example dataset.

Comment: Do you have `Month` info in the columns?

Comment: No I have just the number of the day. For example today is the day number 307. The day number 1 is the first of January.

Comment: I will look at it.. What would be more easy it's to tell R to calculate the mean every 18th values; makes groups of 18 values and starts at the beginning of the dataset (I just have to delete the first row)... But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yes, the values are all ordered like this in the chronological order.

Comment: I think I understand the problem.  In your calculation, you are leaving out the first value ie. `x[1]` and then averaging out from `x[2]:x[19]` ie.  `mean(dat$SoilResp[2:19])#[1] 0.2147531`, but in the code, it averages from  `x[1]:x[18]` ie. `mean(dat$SoilResp[1:18])#[1] 0.3604722`.  So, I am guessing you wanted to start from `01` instead of `00`

Comment: The first script doesn't work because it makes groups with the values after the precise hour. For example, group 3 regroups the values at 3:00, 3:10, [...] 5:40, 5:50 and I wanted it to regroup the values at 00:10, 00:20, [...] 2:50, 3:00.

Comment: Yes, this script is working properly. Thank you so much to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
dat$datetime <-  with(dat, as.POSIXct(sprintf('%04d %03d %02d %02d', Year, Day,
                              Hours, Minutes), format='%Y %j %H %M') )

dat$Hgroup <- format(as.POSIXct(cut(dat$datetime, breaks='3 hour')), '%H')

library(dplyr)
res <- dat %>% 
           group_by(Year, Day,Hgroup) %>%
           summarise(MeanSoilResp= mean(SoilResp, na.rm=TRUE))

 head(res,10)
 #   Year Day Hgroup MeanSoilResp
 #1  2012   1     00   0.36047216
 #2  2012   1     03  -0.41095240
 #3  2012   1     06  -0.05942487
 #4  2012   1     09   0.22131365
 #5  2012   1     12   0.33759119
 #6  2012   1     15  -0.07563378
 #7  2012   1     18   0.03608052
 #8  2012   1     21  -0.21778018
 #9  2012   2     00   0.13301751
 #10 2012   2     03  -0.02268468
```

#### Update

If the dataset is ordered, you could try:

```
 indx <- c(0,(1:nrow(dat)-1) %/%18+1)
 dat$indx <- indx[-length(indx)]
 res1 <- dat %>% 
             group_by(indx) %>%
             summarise(MeanSoilResp= mean(SoilResp, na.rm=TRUE))
 head(res1,3)
 #     indx MeanSoilResp
 #1     0  1.254720853
 #2     1  0.214753060
 #3     2 -0.273466865
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(142)
 dat <- data.frame(Year=2012, Day=rep(1:14, each=144,
     length.out=2000), Hours= rep(0:23, each=6,
     length.out=2000),Minutes=rep(seq(0,50,by=10),
     length.out=2000), SoilResp=rnorm(2000))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The script works but I don't obtain the results I would like to obain. With the data (dat), if I calculate the means manually (x=dat$SoilResp
x1=x[1]
c1=c(x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],x[10],x[11],x[12],x[13],x[14],x[15],x[16],x[17],x[18],x[19])
x2=mean(c1)
x2
c2=c(x[20],x[21],x[22],x[23],x[24],x[25],x[26],x[27],x[28],x[29],x[30],x[31],x[32],x[33],x[34],x[35],x[36],x[37])
x3=mean(c2)
x3). I obtain : 1.254721,  0.2147531,  -0.2734669 for the 3 first means. It's not what we obtain with the script...

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, the following script is working perfectly :

`indx <- c(0,(1:nrow(dat)-1) %/%18+1)`

`dat$indx <- indx[-length(indx)]`

`res1 <- dat %>%`

`group_by(indx) %>%`

`summarise(MeanSoilResp= mean(SoilResp, na.rm=TRUE))`

For information, I needed to do this because the data of soil temperature and soil humidity is collected only every 3 hours. To study the relation between temperature / soil humidity and soil respiration I have 2 possibilities :

- decimation modelling : I use only the soil respiration values each 3 hours
- aggregation modelling : 3 hours means