# How I can calculate the max min value, the mean and standard deviation of a variable every certain time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, statistics

I have the data of 30 days of Temperature and other 5 variables, i already split them and get every day as a variable(Day1 ,Day2 ,Day3 ,.....,Day30),the FIRST PART of the work is plot the graphs individually and then overlay in a graph the 30 days and see a pattern of behavior, then in the SECOND PART I need to calculate the max and min value, the mean and standard deviation of the Temperature variable every 10 minutes for each day, get aprox 144 values for every day. Im working with the .txt data in the following link:  **mega.nz/#!cDQGCISJ!LUD9JhJIOVGyhmS8iyHQo6x9V9KWUdfR0_T882PAv0c** every day looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlR7P.png)

And I need to calculate the (Min and Max Value of T, the mean and Standard Deviation every 10 minutes until the day finish and make it like that for the other 29 days) I want Python count the minutes and make this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUTOl.jpg)

and the code i have so far is the following with only the first part(the code for plot the graph individually and the overlay plot with the 30 days) i need help for the :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import datetime as dt
import calendar
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt 
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns

datos = pd.read_csv("Jun2019.txt", sep = ',', names=('Fecha', 'Hora', 'RADNETA', 'RADCORENT', 'RADCORSAL', 'RADINFENT', 'RADINFSAL', 'TEMP'))

datos['Hora'] = datos['Hora'].str[:9] **#Use this part to get rid of the miliseconds(mm.xxxx)**
datos['Hora']

Dia01Jun2019 = datos[datos['Fecha'] == "2019-06-01"] 

tiempo01=Dia01Jun2019['Hora']
temp01=Dia01Jun2019['TEMP']

imagen = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
plt.plot(tiempo01,temp01)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 54977, 7000)) 
plt.xlabel("Tiempo (H:M:S)(Formato 24 Horas)")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura (K)")
plt.title("Día 01 Jun 2019")
plt.show()
imagen.savefig('D1JUN2019')
```

The code repeats for every day just that i dont put here cause is to long and then the overlay part is(credits to Mig B community user that helped me with the following code):

```
imagen = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))

for day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,26,27,28,30]:
    dia = datos[datos['Fecha'] == "2019-06-"+(f"{day:02d}")]
    tiempo= pd.to_datetime(dia['Hora'], format=' %H:%M:%S').dt.time
    temp= dia['TEMP']
    plt.plot(tiempo, temp) #, color = 'red' )# 

plt.xlabel("Tiempo (H:M:S)(Formato 24 Horas)")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura (K)")
plt.title("Temperatura Jun 2019")
plt.show()
imagen.savefig('TEMPJUN2019')
```

And this is the code so far , i dont have and idea to calculate the SECOND PART, I appreciate every help to make the second part, for the record the loop `for day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,26,27,28,30]:` I omit some days because they had measurement problems.

Some previous value information maybe can be found in a previous question that i made here [How to make overlay plots of a variable, but every plot than i want to make has a different length of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367119/how-to-make-overlay-plots-of-a-variable-but-every-plot-than-i-want-to-make-has/58383342#58383342)

*Also someone ask something similar in here if that help as a guide [Group the values for a certain time interval and calculate the means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713609/group-the-values-for-a-certain-time-interval-and-calculate-the-means)
 Just that he had data every 10 minutes and want the mean every 3 hours get 8 values for day , And in my case I have the data every aprox 2 minutes , want the mean every 10 minutes and get aprox 144 values for day.*

Answer (score 0):

```
df.iloc[[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,26,27,28,30],:].describe()
```

for index [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,26,27,28,30].

To set the day as index:

```
df = df.set_index('column_name_of_your_day')
```

If you want to slice each 5 rows:

```
for i in range(0,len(df),5):
    df.iloc[i:i+5,:].describe()
```

Comment: Once  I put this lines above and index the days, how I can calculate those values(min, max, mean, standard deviation) every 10 minutes,In resume of my question once i index the days how i can tell python to access to a single day and calculate the values I need every certain time (10 min in this case) , I modify the post for you to look how the day 01 looks

Comment: Do u apply fixed window or rolling window? For example, from 0am to 1am, do u need 6 data(every 10 minutes) or you want 60 data each has a moving window as you specify? For first one, you can dynamically index your slicer, for the latter you need rolling_window

Comment: I dont know what it is rolling window or fixed window but i need this for example, I have this: 
00:00:00, 00:00:02, 00:00:05, 00:00:08, 00:00:0

Comment: I dont know what it is rolling window or fixed window but i need this for example, I have this 5 first rows: 
00:01:00, 00:02:00, 00:05:05, 00:08:08, 00:10:25 . I need the mean of those 5 lines, as one value, then repeat it for the next values 00:10:25, 00:12:00, 00:15:05, 00:18:08, 00:20:43 get another mean as one value for those other 5 lines, the point is that i need a mean() every 10 minutes of the data

Comment: for i in range(0,len(df),5): df.iloc[i:i+5,:]

Comment: Can you modify the post to see it more clearly what i have to put in the code to make the calculation, im not so good in python so im a little confused, sorry for bother

Comment: thanks im gonna try it please stay online if i hace a doubt jaja

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the df.iloc[i:i+5;:].describe()

Comment: df.iloc select row base on index, [i:i+5,:] means from index i to i+5, with all columns, df.describe() is a lazy way to get statistics like min/max/percentile

Comment: hey chrisckwong821 can i talk with you by twitter about this? i tried to compile it but when the code runs, doesnt show errors but even a result